# Did G.K. Chesterton ever write specifically about a Christian's moral responsibilities?

Tags: morality, books, g-k-chesterton

As a school assignment I'm supposed to compare two authors on the topic of morality. Specifically the question is: how ought a person to relate to Christianity / how should Christianity affect one's life? I was really hoping that Chesterton could be one of my authors, but I'm struggling to find a place where he writes about that topic.

Here's where I've read of him so far:

- For fiction, I've read some Father Brown and The Man Who Was Thursday.
- For nonfiction, I've read some of Orthodoxy, most of What's Wrong w/ the World, and most of Everlasting Man.

I was especially hoping that Everlasting Man would give me good fodder, but it seems like he's making more of a historical / anthropological argument instead of a moral one. Anyway, I'm sort of at my wits end here, and would love input.

tldr; Does anyone have a suggestion for a good Chesterton book/essay that talks about morality?

Comment: Came across your question because I was looking for something similar. In Mere Christianity, CS Lewis says, 

> "As Chesterton pointed out, those who are in love have a natural
> inclination to bind themselves by promises. Love songs all over the
> world are full of vows of eternal constancy..."

I'm looking for the place where Chesterton says this. It may be what you're looking for as well. Good luck!